# How to display monthly balance for month with no balance SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have the following block of code which I am using to query a SQL Server database that summarizes all balances for each of the previous 13 months. It works pretty good, but there are a few months when there were no balances to report. These months are not displaying which I do need. At this point, I am at a loss for what to try next.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE;

SELECT 
    @StartDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), DATEADD(month, -13, GETDATE())),
    @EndDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), DATEADD(month, 0, GETDATE()));

;WITH d(d) AS
(
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0))
    FROM 
        (SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
             n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
         FROM 
             sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id]) AS n
)
SELECT
    FORMAT(d.d, 'MMM yy') AS Purchase_Date,
    CAST(ROUND(SUM(lm.BALANCE), 0) AS FLOAT) AS Balance
FROM 
    d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.purchases AS lm ON lm.purchase_date >= d.d
                        AND lm.purchase_date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, d.d)
WHERE 
    lm.Buyer_code = 'FirstTime'
    AND lm.PROGRAM_ID = 'NewBuyers'
GROUP BY 
    d.d
ORDER BY 
    d.d
```

Comment: replace `where` with `and` and see the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the `LEFT JOIN` by the where clause, which requires that every row have certain values from the left joined table. In effect it is equivalent to an inner join. You **need to allow rows from d to survive into the result**, which you can do by using the wanted conditions directly in the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT( d.d, 'MMM yy' )                        AS Purchase_Date
  , CAST( ROUND( SUM( lm.BALANCE ), 0 ) AS float ) AS Balance
FROM d
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.purchases AS lm ON lm.purchase_date >= d.d
    AND lm.purchase_date < DATEADD( MONTH, 1, d.d )
    AND lm.Buyer_code = 'FirstTime'
    AND lm.PROGRAM_ID = 'NewBuyers
GROUP BY
    d.d
ORDER BY
    d.d
```

Comment: Ya, that did it. A few additional tweaks and I now have the query displaying what I need it to display. I am so happy! Thanks.